# How to resolve cyclomatic complexity in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code to set height based on conditions and devices. But, I get an error - Cyclomatic complexity is too high (28) for this. How can I resolve it?

```css
function adjustHeightForAttributes() {
        
            var elementHeight = document.getElementById('listSearchOptions');
            var childNoLen = $('.attributelistContainer .requestedAttr span').length;
            
            if (childNoLen >= 1) {
                $('.attributelistContainer').css({"overflow-y":"auto"}); 
            }
            
            // Establishing media check
            var widthMinCheck = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches;
            var widthMaxCheck = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)").matches;
            var orientationCheck = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches;
            var orientationCheckPortrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches;
            //True / False values check
            var bothFalse = vm.searchByRoomNo === false && childNoLen === 0;
            var bothTrue = vm.searchByRoomNo === true && childNoLen >= 1;
            var roomSearchTrue = vm.searchByRoomNo === true && childNoLen === 0;
            var childLenTrue = vm.searchByRoomNo === false && childNoLen >= 1;
            //Check if scroll exists
            var scrollExists = $('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight > $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight;
            
            if (widthMinCheck && widthMaxCheck && orientationCheck) {
                console.log("oreintationCheck.. " + orientationCheck);
                if (bothFalse) {
                    if(scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight6." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"auto", "max-height":""});                   
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight7." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"52vh","max-height":"52vh"});  
                    }
                }
                if (childLenTrue) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight1." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"38vh"});                    
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight2." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"40vh"});  
                    }
                }
                if (bothTrue) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight3." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"30vh"});                    
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight4." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"32vh"});  
                    }
                    
                }
                if (roomSearchTrue) {
                    if ($('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight > $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight5." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"44vh"});                    
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight5." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"46vh"});  
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (orientationCheckPortrait) {
                if (bothFalse) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight6." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"auto", "max-height":""});                   
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight7." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"42vh"});  
                    }
                }
                if (childLenTrue) {
                    if ($('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight > $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight1." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"38vh"});                    
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight2." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"40vh"});  
                    }
                }
                if (bothTrue) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight3." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"30vh"});                    
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight4." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"32vh"});  
                    }
                    
                }
                if (roomSearchTrue) {
                    if ($('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight > $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight5." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"45vh"});                    
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight5." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"48vh"});  
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if (bothFalse) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight6." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"height":"auto", "max-height":""});
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight7." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"42vh"});
                    }
                }
                if (childLenTrue) {
                    if ($('#listSearchOptions')[0].scrollHeight > $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight8." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"27.2vh"});
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight9." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"27vh"});
                    }
                }
                if (roomSearchTrue) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight10." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                       $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"34vh"});
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight11." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"36vh"});
                    }
                }
                if (bothTrue) {
                    if (scrollExists) {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight12." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"18.5vh"});
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight13." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
                        $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"20.8vh"});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try the refactored logic in my answer. Hope it will give you more control on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiki of Cyclomatic complexity is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Cyclomatic complexity is being counted on a method depend on branch statement. Like if, else, for , while etc.

If you refactor your method to multiple method and keep less number of if else in each method your problem will be solved.

In your code there is lots of if else and inner if is there. Try to refactor those as follows.

```
function bothTrue_scrollExists(bothTrue, scrollExists)
    if (bothTrue) {
        if (scrollExists) {
            console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight12." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
            $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"18.5vh"});
        }
        else {
            console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight13." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
            $('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":"20.8vh"});
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Try to refactor your logic to better implementation as follows.

```
var s = '';

if (widthMinCheck && widthMaxCheck && orientationCheck) {
    s = s + 'A';
}
else if (orientationCheckPortrait) {
    s = s + 'B';
}
else{
    s = s + 'C';
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
if (bothFalse) {
    s=s+'_'+'BF';
}
else if (childLenTrue){
    s=s+'_'+'CT';
}
else if (roomSearchTrue){
    s=s+'_'+'RS';
}
else if (bothTrue){
    s=s+'_'+'BT';
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
if (scrollExists) {
    s=s+'_'+'SE';
}
else {
    s=s+'_'+'NS';
}
var data = {
     'A_BF_NS' : 52,
     'B_BF_SE' : 38//Put other combinations here
};
console.log("Height..in adjustSearchAttributesheight." + $('#listSearchOptions')[0].clientHeight);
var height = (data[s])? data[s] : 'auto';
$('#listSearchOptions').css({"max-height":height+"vh"});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity):

> It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.

Each control statement (if/else, for etc) will add to the cyclomatic complexity of a function.

You should look for ways to refactor your function into multiple smaller functions.